# Deploying Android app stuck at uninstalling package

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, adb

So, I'm developing this Xamarin Forms app for Android and iOS and it's been running fine for well over a year until now. Visual Studio refuses to deploy my Android app to a real device (Samsung S10+, SM-G975F) running Android 10.

When trying to deploy, both in Debug and in Release modes, VS copies the files over to my device, reaches 100% and then states

> Looks like the package `com.companyname.packageId` is already installed, trying to uninstall it first.

Then nothing happens. It's stuck.

I've tried to uninstall manually through the device itself but the App can't be found. I've tried the adb command `adb shell pm uninstall com.companyname.packageId` and the command just hangs and won't continue/fail or anything.

Both my PC and device have been rebooted. Even installed the latest Samsung Phone drivers for Windows without success. I'm kind of lost at this point as I don't have any other device to test on, and doing a factory reset on my device would be the absolute last resort.

*note: I can deploy to an emulator, and I can download the app from Google Play. I just can't deploy from VS*

VS output from Build:

```
Signed android package 'bin\Debug\com.companyname.packageId-Signed.apk'
Detecting installed packages...
Copying application to device...
10% ... 1536kb of 15073kb copied
20% ... 3072kb of 15073kb copied
30% ... 4544kb of 15073kb copied
40% ... 6080kb of 15073kb copied
50% ... 7552kb of 15073kb copied
60% ... 9088kb of 15073kb copied
70% ... 10560kb of 15073kb copied
80% ... 12096kb of 15073kb copied
90% ... 13568kb of 15073kb copied
100% ... 15073kb of 15073kb copied
 Looks like the package `com.companyname.packageId` is already installed, trying to uninstall it first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the App was installed in the "Secure Folder"(Samsung Knox) on my device. Browsing the Secure Folder and then uninstalling the App seems to have fixed the issue and I can once again deploy to my real device.

Comment: I never thought this would be a case. My app was installed in the "Secure Folder".